# iPhone 6, iOS 8.1 reports 320x568 points screen on Device, but 375x667 on Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, iphone-6

I'm using iOS 8.1, Xcode 6.1 on both Device and Simulator.

```
NSLog(@"SCREEN (%i x %i) SCALE: %i", (int)[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, (int)[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, (int)[UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
```

Result on Device: SCREEN (320 x 568) SCALE: 2

Result on Simulator: SCREEN (375 x 667) SCALE: 2

I have used Asset Catalog, Default image for iPhone 6 (750x1334px) is displayed correctly on Simulator, but again iPhone 5 one (640x1136px) is displayed on Device.

PS. iPhpne 6 Plus works perfectly on both Device and Simulator reporting SCREEN (414 x 736) SCALE: 3, which is correct.

My app should use the exact images and layouts for all devices by design.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same happens if create a new blank project. :(

Comment: May be when you made setup for your new iPhone you chose ZOOM mode for device?

Comment: @nerowolfe - right you are!!! I was sure this mode is only about home screen icon sizes. Thank you, please post as an answer to this question.

Comment: And the most interesting is if you setup iPhone 6 Plus in ZOOM mode you will be reported iPhone 6 screen with scale 3 :)
SCREEN (375 x 667) SCALE: 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be when you made setup for your new iPhone you chose ZOOM mode for device?

Comment: Removed comment

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two ways to ZOOM on the iPhone:
1) The one relevant to this issue is at: "Settings - Display & Brightness - View"
and set to "Standard" to turn off the Zoom.
2) Another one at: "Settings - General - Accessibility - Zoom" is not relevant to this issue.